# Javascript hit counter

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning Javascript, and I attempted to write code for hit counter for a webpage using Javascript. I know that we have to use cookies to get the correct number and use PHP to modify data stored in servers. But could you please debug this for me ? I'm getting the output as "The number of visitors is: NaN"

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>The number of visitors is : <span id="cntr">0</span></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function counter_fn() {
      var counter = document.getElementById("cntr");
      var count = 0;
      count = counter.value;
      count = count + 1;
      counter.innerHTML = count;
    }
    window.onload = counter_fn;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the `value`from a `span` element, which is wrong. 
Your `counter.value` is `undefined` so it will give you the wrong answer.

You can get the `0`  from the `span` by using `document.getElementById("cntr").innerHTML`. But the value returned is in `string`. So you need to do `parseInt` to convert it into `integer` and only then your addition will give you the correct value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>The number of visitors is : <span id="cntr">0</span></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function counter_fn() {
      var counter = document.getElementById("cntr");
      var count = 0;
      count = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
      count = count + 1;
      counter.innerHTML = count;
    }
    window.onload = counter_fn;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm. Only that Javascript cannot be used to modify the file saved in the disk, so after each load it will show '1' as the value is not written in the html file in the disk.

Comment: I have only pointed out the mistakes in your code and how to rectify it.

Comment: You are hard coding the value and incrementing it. You need to first load the initial count from the disk and then increment it. But the code you have provided, doesn't picks the initial value from the disk. It is hard coded as `0` so will always increment to `1`.

Comment: Yes indeed. I realised that mistake. Is it possible to do what you suggest using only Javascript?

Comment: You should either use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` if you want to store the value in your browser

Comment: Okay, that still doesnt solve the problem.. When multiple users are visiting the same website.

Comment: Then you need to store the count in database and retrieve it from there. That's the only way to keep track of users .

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseInt`

```
<script> 
    function counter_fn(){
       var counter = document.getElementById("cntr");
       var count = 0;
       count = parseInt(counter.value);
       count = count+1;
       counter.innerHTML = parseInt(count);
    }
    window.onload = counter_fn;  
 </script>
```

**UPDATE**

As `@Anurag Singh Bisht` commented, `you cannot get value from a span element` . So to get value from `<span>` you need to use `$('span').text();`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="cntr"> 
            The number of visitors is : 
            <span>0</span>
        </div>

       <script> 
            function counter_fn(){
                var counter = $('#cntr span').text(); // geting value from span
                var count = 0;
                count = parseInt(counter.value);
                count = count+1;
                counter.innerHTML = parseInt(count);
           }
           window.onload = counter_fn;  
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong as you cannot get `value` from a `span` element. You are just doing `parseInt` in the `undefined` value.

Comment: to get value from `<span>` you can use` $('span').text();`

Comment: Thank you very much, but this doesn't increase the count.. do you know what could be the reason ?

Comment: check the value you get here `var counter = $('#cntr span').text();` use `alert(counter )`

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string to an integer and you need to get the innerHTML.

```
<script> 
  function counter_fn(){
    var counterElement = document.getElementById("cntr")
    var counterNumber = parseInt(counterElement.innerHTML)
    counterNumber = counterNumber + 1
    counterElement.innerHTML = counterNumber
  }
  window.onload = counter_fn;  
</script>
```

The correct way to do it would be storing this value somewhere else, like localStorage and reading it from there. You are not supposed to read your own HTML to update the value. HTML elements are supposed to be results, not your input.

```
var counterNumber = 1

if (localStorage.getItem("count")) {
  counterNumber = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count")) + 1
}
else {
  localStorage.setItem("count", counterNumber)
}
```

Comment: It worked. But each refresh only shows '1' , as the value does not get stored in the html file in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

To fix every refresh showing 1 (refer comment for Eren Tanteken suggestion), we need to add another line as shown below:

```
var counterNumber = 1

if (localStorage.getItem("count")) {
  counterNumber = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count")) + 1
  localStorage.setItem("count", counterNumber)
}
else {
  localStorage.setItem("count", counterNumber)
}
```

This way we will be updating the new value in local storage. Hope this helps